# How write query to Check Zip code of 5 numbers and State of 2 letters only while creating table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
    userID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    City VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    State VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    Zip INT NOT NULL, 
    CHECK (Zip < 6 AND Zip > 4 AND State < 3 AND State > 1)
)
```

I'm creating new table user. I try to put check of zip code 5 numbers and State of 2 letters. How do i do this using "LIke" in the query. Also, check i'm using is not working either. 
Can some one help me how to check zip code of 5 number and state of 2 letters using LIKE ?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Please edit your question to use the appropriate tag.

Comment: What is `state`?  Is that like US state?  But how can that only have a value of `2`?   Maybe you mean two characters?

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes your right, I mean only 2 letters for state, example would be FL for Florida. It has to be only 2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

For Zip, How about using

```
CHECK (Zip BETWEEN 00001 AND 99999)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you want something more like this:

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
    userID   INT                   PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    City     VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL, 
    State    CHAR(2)      NOT NULL,
    Zip      CHAR(5)      NOT NULL, 
)
```

The `CHECK` clause doesn't work all that great:  It is [parsed but ignored](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) on all storage engines but InnoDB.  (See the linked documentation beginning with *"For other storage engines"*.)  InnoDB uses it, at a minimum, to check foreign keys.  It may or may not check anything for ordinary column values.